# How to use dependency injection to inject object into module?

Tags: python, dependency-injection, module

This is my scenario. I have a package that consists of several modules. They all import from `settings.py`. Some of the variable, though, depend on user input.

```
...
# some CONSTANTS
...
PROJECT_DIR = Path(os.path.abspath(__file__)).parent.ancestor(1)
SCRIPT_DIR = PROJECT_DIR.child('scripts')
data_input = DATA_ROOT.child('input')
input_root = data_input.child(options.root_input) # the options object holds some user input

# then use input_root to get an instance of class Countries
from countries import Countries
country_object = Countries(input_root)
```

there are several modules that need the `country_object`. So importing them from `settings` would be the cleanest solutions.

So I was reading up on `dependency injection` and I think this is what comes in handy here. But I find it difficult to wrap my around it so how would one use dependency injection to inject the options object into a module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to patterns there are two philosophies, make your problem fit the pattern and make the pattern fit your problem. I follow the latter. So this would be my adaption of the `dependency injection` pattern to your problem:

```
class UserCountry(object):
     def __init__(self):be populated by user data
         self.Country = None

     def set_input_root(self, input_root):
         self.input_root = input_root # <-- this is a list/dict etc that I assume will 

     def __call__(self):
         if self.Country:
             return self.Country
         else:
             # Select country
             self.Country = Country
             return self.Country
```

in `settings.py`:

```
 user_country = UserCountries()
```

when `input_root` is defined:

```
settings.user_country.set_input_root(input_root)
```

in other modules:

```
 settings.user_country() # gives you the Country object
```

Comment: But `settings.py` does not know anything about `input_root`. So I can't call `UserCountries()` from within settings. I could call it from my main program but the problem remains as other modules also don't know about root_input.

Comment: so when is input_root set?

Comment: @LarsVegas I updated my answer, but you do realize that you won't know input_root, before you know input root...

Comment: it depends on user input, so when the main program is invoked. But the main program already imports from settings. Other modules than the main program will import settings as well. A module might use another module of the package as well outside of the main program. So input_root and country-instance must be valid and accessible globally during execution of the main program.

Comment: Have you seen my updated version? As long as `set_input_root` is set in the main program before the actual country is needed anywhere you should be fine. You may want to add a default and also save it to the database, if sessions are persistent.